# Conflicting specifiers in declaration c++

Tags: c++, boost-bimap

I use a data structure `bimap`

```
typedef boost::bimap< std::string, int > hash_bimap;
typedef hash_bimap::value_type position;
hash_bimap perm;
```

and it works fine in main file. However, i am interested to use it in header file to make it accessible in any other `.cpp` file.

when I try to make it `extern` in `my.h` like

```
extern typedef boost::bimap< std::string, int > hash_bimap;
extern typedef hash_bimap::value_type position;
extern hash_bimap perm;
```

> conflicting specifiers in declaration of ‘hash_bimap’
>    extern typedef boost::bimap< std::string, int > hash_bimap;

Comment: typedef doesn't declare anything the linker can see, so you don't need to/can't make it extern.

Comment: @kfsone Thanks !! How to make it accessible to other `.cpp` file

Comment: Just include the header with the typedefs in the other `cpp` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(elaborating on kfsone's comment) `typedef`s don't need to be extern, just the actual variable:

```
typedef boost::bimap< std::string, int > hash_bimap;
typedef hash_bimap::value_type position;
extern hash_bimap perm;
```